# How to shrink the whole page to center when it is zoomed out?

Tags: html, css, responsiveness, responsive

If the page is zoomed out , how can i shrink the webpage and all of its content to center?
This is before zooming out.
[image: This is before zooming out]
This is after zooming out
[image: After zooming out]

How to shrink to center of the page while zooming out?

Code im using is

```
    <title>Demo</title>
<head>This is a demo</head>
<style>
#my-div{

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  width: 80%;
  height: 50%;
}
#nav
{
background-color: red;
float: left;
width: 200px;
position:relative;

}

#detail
{
background-color: green;
float : right;
width: 800px;
position:relative;
}

div.testDetail 
{
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#container
{
width:1000px;
position:relative;
}
</style>

<hr>
<body style="background-color:blue";>


<div id="my-div">
<div id="container">
<div id="nav">
    <ul>Tests</ul>
</div>
<div id="detail">
    <div class="testDetail">
        <image style="float:right;margin:5px;" src="test1.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
        <image style="float:right;margin:5px;" src="test2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
        <image style="float:right;margin:5px;" src="test3.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
        <image style="float:right;margin:5px;" src="test4.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Testing</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
</div>
<body>
```

Comment: Please provide example code. You could probably add `margin: auto` to make sure the content is centered.

Comment: provide code example, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: yes,I have shared that example code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can share code example ?

You may try to use css property :

`margin:0 auto;` in order to center your block (perhaps body in your case).

Regards.

[Edit]

First you have mistake in your HTML:

1. close body tag correctly
2. remove ';' in open body tag
3. wrap code with html tag
4. Add doctype (html5 used in my code)
5. put style within head tag
6. put title within head tag
7. remove text node in head tag

Please indent too.

[Edit]

Here code works after corrections, I use percent instead of pixel dimension, enjoy :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Demo</title>
        <style>
            body{
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #my-div{
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 80%;
                height: 50%;
            }

            #nav
            {
                background-color: red;
                float: left;
                width: 20%;
                position:relative;

            }

            #detail
            {
                background-color: green;
                float : right;
                width: 80%
                position:relative;
            }

            div.testDetail
            {
                margin-top:10px;
                margin-left:20px;
                margin-right:20px;
                margin-bottom:10px;
            }

            #container
            {
                width:auto;
                position:relative;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:blue">
        <div id="my-div">
            <div id="container">
                <div id="nav">
                    <ul>Tests</ul>
                </div>
                <div id="detail">
                    <div class="testDetail">
                        <image style="float:right;margin:5px;" src="test1.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
                        <image style="float:right;margin:5px;" src="test2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
                        <image style="float:right;margin:5px;" src="test3.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
                        <image style="float:right;margin:5px;" src="test4.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>Testing</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use bootstrap framework in css

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/xkzomtvd/2/

Keep the whole page in main div and apply class on that
for example:

all content here

give style to this class:

.wrapper {

```
margin:0 auto;
max-width:400px; /* required width fixed or percentage */
background:red;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are actually centering the page, it's just not obvious right away. The reason is the width of 80% in your #my-div element, whereas all of their children are within a 1000px container.

This will solve your problem:

```
#my-div{
    width: 1000px;
}
```

You could use `max-width` alternatively, but for your example, there really isn't a reason to.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
}
```